# Why in ConstraintLayout one item is NOT over another

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Android Studio 2.6

I want ImageView to be OVER MaterialCardView.

I try this

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/cardPaymentContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/button_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/button_margin"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolBarContainer">


            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/cardPaymentCardView"
                style="@style/cardViewIconStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:checkable="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_view_cornder_radius"
                app:checkedIcon="@drawable/ic_credit_card_outline_select"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cardPaymentImageViewContainer"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:background="@drawable/card_payment_view_bg"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here result:

[image]

As you can see it's not work.

The ImageView is **UNDER** MaterialCardView.

Comment: If I remember correctly `CardView` is implicitly elevated by some amount and that's why it appears over the `ImageView`.

Comment: So how I can fix this?

Comment: Set a big enough `android:elevation` value to the `ImageView`, or move the `ImageView` inside the `CardView`.

Comment: after set in ImageView -> android:elevation="1dp" -> it's help. Or this in CardView -> app:cardElevation="0dp" . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the default Z Axis behavior of CardView by updating elevation. set `cardElevation` to 0dp.

```
app:cardElevation="0dp"
```